# C++ using Max function to find a list of ints

Tags: c++, max

These are my ints for the program I am writing is it possible to somehow find the max and then set it to an int? Later down my code the ints do not equal 0. Just below is what I would like the code to do.

```
int Max = std::max(Face1,Face2, "and so on") << '\n';
```

```
#include <algorithm>
void RollDice() {
int Rolls = 0;
int Seed = 0;
int Random = 0;
int Face1 = 0;
int Face2 = 0;
int Face3 = 0;
int Face4 = 0;
int Face5 = 0;
int Face6 = 0;
```

Thanks any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want std::max({a, b, c, ...}) where ... is your "and so on" ?

Comment: Basically I want to take those Face1- Face6 and find the max value of them using the max function.

Comment: Why not use an array of 6 items instead of 6 separate variables?

Comment: @SgtOVERKILL Then pass a initializer_list by adding {} to std::max({...})

Comment: Why not putting the `Face[n]` variables into a `std::vector<int>` and use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Isn't that all 'int'?

Comment: @DieterLücking My bad.  Your right.  it just needs to be wrapped with `{}`.

Comment: The array / vector will probably not only help with the `std::max`, it more than likely would reduce a lot of the other code you have now that uses 6 separate variables.

Answer (score 3):

While it might be argued that it would be better to have an array of N faces to do this, to use std::max the way you are asking you just need to turn the list into an initializer list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int Face1 = 10, Face2 = 5, Face3 = 8, Face4 = 20, Face5 = 21, Face6 = 9;
    std::cout << std::max({ Face1, Face2, Face3, Face4, Face5, Face6 }) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/TcJKGt

Answer (score 1):

Just use std::max with an initializer list (put all variables in between `{...}`) :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int Face1 = 0;
    int Face2 = 1;
    int Face3 = 2;
    int Face4 = 3;
    int Face5 = 2;
    int Face6 = 1;
    std::cout << std::max({ Face1, Face2, Face3, Face4, Face5, Face6 }) << '\n';
}
```

An alternative is using an array (c-array, std::array, std::vector, ...)  - many variables acting as an array may be cumbersome - and use `std::max_element` (as mentioned by @πάντα ῥεῖ).

Comment: Thank you so much i did not have the {..} that makes it a lot easier for me rather than using a vector at this point in time!

Comment: Is there a way to save that max output to a new int?

Comment: @SgtOVERKILL Just put it to an int, avoid new/delete